# Django: Multi-tenancy translations

Tags: django

I want to ask you something important for me. Is it possible to make translations or verbose_name to be user (tenant) based. I mean following case: For one user 'Charge Point' is 'Point' but for another user is 'Connector'. Is it possible my model verbose_name to be defined by user and every user see him translation?

Comment: hm, maybe you are looking for contenttypes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: No, i look for some solution, that one model may have more than one name. And this names should be set from user, not from me.

Comment: so what is a problem? render fields manually and set specific  `label` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually